# URL encoded character replacement with predefined characters

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, urlencode, url-encoding

I am trying to fool-proof dynamic generation or url's so that there are no ugly url encoded characters. I generate url's with data from the MySQL database.

For example I have the title field that I generate the url from by replacing spaces with dashes (-).

```
domain.com/movie/the-terminator/
```

The issue is that I cannot anticipate all the character that might be in the title. This means that the generated url is not going to match the actual url in the browser bar because it will get encoded.

Is there any php code available that does this replacement? I wouldn't want to do it manually as there are a lot of character to be encoded. I would also like to have few other character replaced such as brackets "(" and ")". The may be a special php method to replace url encoded characters with a defined value, if so please let me know as that may solve my problem very easily, thanks.

Comment: You would typically implement this when adding the record for whatever "slug" is derived from tothe database. It would then save this slug along with everything else. Then you let user know whats acceptable if they want to enter one manually or make it automatically derive from another field (like the title) if they dont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this link. http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator - "THE PERFECT PHP CLEAN URL GENERATOR"

example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, Thanks!

Comment: As this answer may fulfill OP's question, it is best to include essential part of the code in your answer as that website may get unavailable at some point. I have edited it for you.